# HTML: Having trouble getting tooltip overflow:visible to work with position:relative div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that needs to have relative positioning and limited width and height. I want scrollbars added if the content overflows. For this, I have style overflow:auto. This much works. Now I have a tooltip that I want to display when mousing over a target. I want the tooltip to display in its entirety, so it should display beyond the bounds of the enclosing div if necessary. For that I have the tooltip style overflow:visible. Problem is, the tooltip does not display beyond the bounds of the div. If I remove the positioning of the div, it works as expected: the div has the scrollbar, and the tooltip extends beyond the div. How can I get this to work when the div is relatively positioned? Any assistance would be appreciated.

```css
        .tooltip {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 18px;
            height: 18px;
            background-color: steelblue;
            color: yellow;
            border: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: central;
            cursor: help;
        }

            .tooltip:before {
                content: '?';
            }

            .tooltip + .tooltiptext {
                position: absolute;
                display: none;
                margin: 5px;
                padding: 5px;
                min-width: 200px;
                max-width: 400px;
                background-color: steelblue;
                color: #fff;
                text-align: left;
                border-radius: 6px;
                overflow: visible;
            }

            .tooltip:hover + .tooltiptext {
                display: inline;
            }


        .scrollIfNeeded {
            position: relative;
            left: 100px;
            top: 100px;
            overflow: auto;
            background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
        }
```

```html
<div id="ModePage" class="scrollIfNeeded" style="width:300px; max-height:100px; margin-right:5px;">
        <span class="tooltip"></span>
        <span class="tooltiptext">
            This is my tooltip. I want it to display beyond the bounds of the ModePage div. I have the tooltip style set to overflow:visible, however it is behaving as if it inherits the setting of the ModePage div. 
        </span>
        Scale: <input id="ScaleUpButton" type="text" /> This is some extra text to make the vertical scrollbar appear. This is some extra text to make the vertical scrollbar appear. This is some extra text to make the vertical scrollbar appear. This is some extra text to make the vertical scrollbar appear. This is some extra text to make the vertical scrollbar appear. This is some extra text to make the vertical scrollbar appear. 
    </div>
```

Comment: What about using the `title` attribute?

Comment: With the way you have it coded right now, you can't.  Since you have `position: relative;` on the parent, and 'overflow: auto;`, the tooltip text is confined to the set dimensions of the parent.

Comment: It would be an acceptable alternative, if I could include HTML elements such as UL in it. Either way, it would be good to understand why my expectations of how it should work are inconsistent with the result.

Comment: Thanks for your response Sean. However it seems the dimensions of the parent aren't the entirety of the issue. If I remove the position: relative, the dimensions don't change yet it behaves as I expect. So it would seem to be the positioning, not the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `position:fixed;` to fix that. try this one

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background-color: steelblue;
  color: yellow;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: central;
  cursor: help;
}
.tooltip:before {
  content: '?';
}
.tooltip + .tooltiptext {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: steelblue;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: visible;
}
.tooltip:hover + .tooltiptext {
  display: inline;

/* here need to set position and width [optionally]*/
  position: fixed;
  max-width: 200px;
}
.scrollIfNeeded {
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="ModePage" class="scrollIfNeeded" style="width:300px; max-height:100px; margin-right:5px;">
  <span class="tooltip"></span>
  <span class="tooltiptext">
            This is my tooltip. I want it to display beyond the bounds of the ModePage div. I have the tooltip style set to overflow:visible, however it is behaving as if it inherits the setting of the ModePage div. 
        </span>
  Scale:
  <input id="ScaleUpButton" type="text" />This is some extra text to make the vertical scrollbar appear. This is some extra text to make the vertical scrollbar appear. This is some extra text to make the vertical scrollbar appear. This is some extra text to make the vertical scrollbar appear.
  This is some extra text to make the vertical scrollbar appear. This is some extra text to make the vertical scrollbar appear.
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks RizkiDPrast, that fixed it! No pun intended. My homework is to figure out why it works. Thanks!!!

Comment: glad it helped. thanks.
 please present your homework submission in a professional manner. 
;)

Comment: I accepted this answer because it works given the scenario I described. I didn't realize however that it doesn't account for scrolling of the document. :( Thanks anyway.

Comment: I think I'm going to use it anyway in lieu of something better. For my purposes that's not a show stopper.